# SQL: omit the FROM clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

When I want to test the behavior of some PostgreSQL function `FOO()` I'd find it useful to execute a query like `SELECT FOO(bar)`, bar being some data I use as a direct input without having to `SELECT` from a real table.

I read we can omit the `FROM` clause in a statement like `SELECT 1` but I don't know the correct syntax for multiple inputs. I tried `SELECT AVG(1, 2)` for instance and it does not work.

How can I do that ?

Comment: AVG is an aggregate, not a regular function, so it has somewhat different semantics.  You could probably use `SELECT SIN(1)` without problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - `but I don't know the correct syntax for multiple inputs`, I think he specifically means aggregate functions anyway.

Comment: @Jonathan: You could define your own AVG that operates on an array though. And yes, `select sin(1)` works fine in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is this just about a misunderstanding concerning aggregate functions or did you want to achieve something else?

Comment: Jonathan is right, my point was about aggregate functions which usually require some rows of data as input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With PostgreSQL you can use a [VALUES expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html) to generate an inlined table:

> VALUES computes a row value or set of row values specified by value expressions. **It is most commonly used to generate a "constant table" within a larger command**, but it can be used on its own.

Emphasis mine. Then you can apply your aggregate function to that "constant table":

```
select avg(x)
from (
    values (1.0), (2.0)
) as t(x)
```

Or just `select expr` if `expr` is not an aggregate function:

```
select sin(1);
```

You could also define your own `avg` function that operates on an array and hide your FROM inside the function:

```
create function avg(double precision[]) returns double precision as $$
    select avg(x) from unnest($1) as t(x);
$$ language 'sql';
```

And then:

```
=> select avg(array[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]);
 avg 
-----
 2.5
```

But that's just getting silly unless you're doing this quite often.

Also, if you're using 8.4+, you can write [variadic functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) and do away with the array. The internals are the same as the array version, you just add `variadic` to the argument list:

```
create function avg(variadic double precision[]) returns double precision as $$
    select avg(x) from unnest($1) as t(x);
$$ language 'sql';
```

And then call it without the array stuff:

```
=> select avg(1.0, 1.2, 2.18, 11, 3.1415927);
    avg     
------------
 3.70431854
(1 row)
```

Thanks to [depesz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80168/depesz) for the [round-about-through-google pointer](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/07/31/waiting-for-84-variadic-functions/) to variadic function support in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You're still expressing a table, but with a more concise syntax.  That table is `t`, with one field aliased as `x`.

Comment: +1 for a very complete answer. Especially liked your use of `variadic` including the links.

Answer (score 4):

To express a SET in most varieties of SQL, you need to actually express a table..

```
 SELECT
  AVG(inlineTable.val)
FROM
(
  SELECT 1 AS Val
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS Val
)
  AS inLineTable
```